# How to copy between two '##'

Tags: cut-copy-paste, custom-text-object

In vim, there is a way to yank between two quotations by using `yi'`. And there is a way to yank between two square brackets by using `yi]`.

I want to do this between two `##`:

```
some_text

## Point #1 --> Copy this
some_code   --> Copy this (cursor here)
some_code2  --> Copy this
## Point #2
```

Also, I would like it to work even if there is no `##` at the end of the file left

```
## Point 1
some_code

## Point 2
some_code

## Point 3   --> Copy this
some_code    --> Copy this
some_code2   --> Copy this (Cursor here)
some_code3   --> Copy this
             --> EOF here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approach is correct, but some tweaks might be needed:

```
function! BlockCopy(pattern)
    call search('^' .. a:pattern, 'cbW')
    normal! 0V
    let l:bottom = search('^' .. a:pattern, 'nW')

    if l:bottom == 0
        normal! G
        call search('.', 'cb')
    else
        execute l:bottom-1
    endif
endfunction
onoremap <silent> m :<C-u>call BlockCopy('##')<CR>
```

This yanks the lines between markdown headers (including the headers themselves). It will also copy at most a single blank line at the end of the file, which is a more reasonable behavior.

Comment: Regarding the yanking between markdown headers, that could be desired but I personally want it to yank the markdown header. Especially because if I run `dm` I can delete the entire section with its header

Comment: But regarding the copying a single blank line; that behaviour is not what I want at all. The last markdown header doesn't have a `##` pattern to find. And thus your code wouldn't be able to interact with that last block.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the comment about the last blank line. In your code, you're yanking to the end of the file. If you have several blank lines there before EOF, then all of them are also being yanked. `normal! }` prevents this.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know about `}`. But that still work if there is a blank line before the end of the section? I'd assume the way to avoid this would be to go the end of the file with `G` and then going back up until you hit a line that has text.

Comment: No, you're right. I forgot about blank lines before EOF. I updated my answer to keep headers and as you said, continue to the end and return to the first character. I think it works reasonably well now.

Comment: Note that in both answers `:normal! G` is the same as `:$` and `:execute 'normal!' (s:bottom-1)..'gg'` is the same as `:execute (s:bottom-1)`. Also note that you should prefer `l:bottom` to `s:bottom`; the former is local to the function, while the latter is scoped to the entire script (file) in which the function is defined.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Excellent. I will change the function to follow your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I used this [tutorial](https://thevaluable.dev/vim-create-text-objects/) to help understand how to do this in lua.
The code to do it is given below, put it in a .lua file and source it from your init.lua to activate it.

```
function block_copy(pattern)
    local top = vim.fn.search('^' .. pattern, 'bW')

    vim.cmd('normal! 0V')

    local bottom = vim.fn.search('^' .. pattern, 'nW')

    if ( bottom == 0)
    then 
        vim.cmd('normal! G')
    else
        vim.cmd('normal! ' .. bottom - 1 .. 'gg')
    end
end

vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('o', 'm', [[:<C-u>lua block_copy('##')<CR>]], { noremap = true, silent = true})
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('x', 'm', [[:<C-u>lua block_copy('##')<CR>]], { noremap = true, silent = true})
```

This can be used as a text-object (use vim's help to read up on it) by using `m`. And it takes in any pattern that you wish.

Comment: Are you sure this code is working as intended? It looks to me that it will yank the header, which is not what you specified in your question. It also jumps to the previous section when the cursor is placed in one of the headers.

Comment: @r_31415  Regarding your points. I do want it to yank the header, that way when I paste it into `ipython` I can see what section was pasted as a double confirmation. The jumping goes back to the first instance of `##` that it finds when searching backwards; that is undesired.

Comment: That's okay, but then your examples show the opposite ("some_code    --> Copy this") and also take a look at that buggy behavior when your cursor is put in headers.

Comment: Yes indeed, my example code wasn't illustrated correctly.

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer according to your actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The [targets plugin](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) gives you this (and
other) functionality.

You can do `yi#`, or `yi,` or any of these:

```
, . ; : + - = ~ _ * # / | \ & $
```

Although this plugin doesn't, and as far as I know can't be coerced to, work for the case where there is no `##` at the end of the file.